# Why is the point-free style called point free in Haskell when it is full with points? Where does the term "point-free" originates from?

Tags: haskell, coding-style, pointfree

I am currently reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and I came across the notion  "[point-free style](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition)" on page 85 as shown below. However, the `fn` function is **full with points**! This confuses me.

- Why is this style of writing functions called "point-free" when it is
  **full** with points ?
- How should I understand this notion ? "Point-free" in what sense ?
- Where is the term "point-free style" originates from ? Perhaps from a
  language where function composition was denoted by space ?

PS: So far this is the only confusing part in this excellent book (i.e. in the first 85 pages I have read so far).

[image]

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> But pointfree has more points!
>
> A common misconception is that the
>   'points' of pointfree style are the (.) operator (function
>   composition, as an ASCII symbol), which uses the same identifier as
>   the decimal point. This is wrong. The term originated in topology, a
>   branch of mathematics which works with spaces composed of points, and
>   functions between those spaces. So a 'points-free' definition of a
>   function is one which does not explicitly mention the points (values)
>   of the space on which the function acts. In Haskell, our 'space' is
>   some type, and 'points' are values. In the declaration  f x = x + 1 we
>   define the function f in terms of its action on an arbitrary point x.
>   Contrast this with the points-free version:  f = (+ 1) where there is
>   no mention of the value on which the function is acting.

from [haskellwiki](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree)

Answer (score 7):

Basically, each local variable is a "point". A function with no local variables is therefore "point-free".